# Почему приложение не обновляется у юзеров

Tags: java, android, google-play

Я загружал приложение в плей маркет,он был установлен у нескольких людей(3-4).Но через пару дней теста были небольшие дополнения,и я поднимал версию а build.gradle чтоб загрузить подписанный apk.На маркете видно что приложение обновилось но у пользователей не обновляется.А при открытии страницы приложения в маркете у них вместо кнопки обновить стоит открыть,знак того что он уже установлен. Хотя там уже другая версия.Почему приложение у них не обновляется? У них у всех стоит автоматическое обновление.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, приложение обновляется волнами. Если в Google Play стоит обновленная версия вашего приложения, то все будет нормально.

[Инструкция по публикации Android-приложения в Google Play](https://habr.com/company/livetyping/blog/326874/):

> Стоит отметить, что неважно, публикуете вы приложение впервые,
>   обновляете существующее или меняете его описание, изменения будут
>   доступны в Google Play не мгновенно, а только через пару часов.

Comment: типо все приложения обновляются группами??

Comment: @Anton Sorokin спасибо.А волны примерно через какое время происходят?

Comment: @SeeSharp вообще я имел ввиду для разных пользователей в разное время, но думаю ваше предположение тоже верное.

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 не знаю. У меня приложение обновлялось дней через 10-15 один раз. Может быть все происходит так, как говорит SeeSharp.

Comment: 10-15 дней плохо.очень плохо.

Comment: Обратите внимание еще что при запуске обновления там было поле, которая отвечает какой процент увидит в приложение обновления. Я не уверено что там можно указать 0%, ну вот 20% это точно. Вы можете это найти в настройках

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 у меня обновления выходят от 10 -180 минут на приложение. Думаю все зависит от нагрузки на гуглплей защиту, которая проверяет приложения. Утром, обычно, обновления прилетают в течении 10 минут. В обед, когда в МСК только утро, обновление уже занимает от 30 минут и до двух часов.